# HBase performance - get al rows with specific column

Tags: hbase

can someone explain how good is the performance when I want to get all rows that contains the column with a specific value?
Is this a linear search?

thank you

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes this a linear search, to find all rows with certain column, you need scan each row in table. The common solution in this case a creation of additional index table. In this table row keys will be column names from data table. Each column in row in this table will be reference to row from main table wich contains a specific column. E.g.

You table

```
| Row   | Column     |      
| RA    | CA         |
        | CB         |
        | CC         |
| RB    | CA         |
        | CC         |
```

Index table

```
| Row   | Column     | 
| CA    | RA         |
        | RB         |
| CB    | RA         |
| CC    | RA         |
        | RB         |
```